# Stop slidetoggle on 3rd submenu and follow link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a complicated submenu generated by a Wordpress widget. It is 4 levels deep.

I'm only showing the first level. Then with the following code, I disable the hyperlink and make the submenu show up.

```
jQuery(function () {
      jQuery('.widget_wpdm_categories_widget ul > li > a').click(function () {               
         jQuery(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
         return false; 
      }) 
    });
```

My problem is that I only want to expend twice. So something like:
Menu item
- Submenu 1
- Submenu 2

Now when you click a link in submenu 2, I DON'T want to expand it. I want to just follow the link.

How do I realize this? My HTML looks like this:

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-41"><a href="http://wptest.alcadis.nl/downloads/metageek/" title="Alle berichten opgeslagen onder Metageek bekijken">Metageek</a>
    <ul class="children" style="display: block;">
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-265"><a href="http://wptest.alcadis.nl/downloads/chanalyzer-metageek/" title="Alle berichten opgeslagen onder Chanalyzer bekijken">Chanalyzer</a>
            <ul class="children" style="display: block;">
                 <li class="cat-item cat-item-266"><a href="http://wptest.alcadis.nl/downloads/pro/" title="Alle berichten opgeslagen onder Pro bekijken">Pro</a>
                      <ul class="children" style="display: block;">
                          <li class="cat-item cat-item-77"><a href="http://wptest.alcadis.nl/downloads/software/" title="Alle berichten opgeslagen onder Software bekijken">Software</a>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                 </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Sometimes when you get into problems like this you need to take a step back and think about usability. A nav menu 4 levels deep can be overwhelming for a user and they will get confused/lost. I also understand that you probably don't have control over the design and you're just trying to get your code to work lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is to just count the parent `<ul>` elements of the link you click on with:

```
if ($(this).parents('ul').length < 3)
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4vQJ6/)**

```
jQuery('.widget_wpdm_categories_widget ul > li > a').click(function () {
    if ($(this).parents('ul').length < 3) {
        jQuery(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem perfectly. Didn't know this was possible in jQuery.